# Localstack PUT object by presigned URL has zero content-length

Tags: aws-sdk, localstack

while using 'localstack/localstack:3.0.2' in integration test (through TestContainers)
Im generating presigned url by SDK JAVA (kotlin)

```
fun getPresignedPutUrl(bucket: String, key: String): String {
        val putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucket)
            .key(key)
            .build()

        val presignedPutRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(putExpiration) // The URL expires in 10 minutes.
            .putObjectRequest(putRequest)
            .build()

        val url = s3presigner.use { it.presignPutObject(presignedPutRequest) }
        return url.url().toExternalForm()
    }
```

Resulting url is used to upload from Spring RestTemplate (groovy)

```
void putFileToPresignedUrl(Resource resource, String presignedUrl) {
        def decodedUri = URLDecoder.decode(presignedUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
        def headers = new HttpHeaders().tap {
            setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        }
        final def body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>().tap {
            set("file", resource)
        }
        def httpEntity = new HttpEntity(body, headers)

        rest.put(decodedUri, httpEntity)
    }
```

There is not much in logs, but inspecting localstack yells:
**AWS s3.PutObject => 200**

After that, using aws cli
`aws s3api --endpoint-url=http://localhost:52552 get-object --key theFile.json --bucket thetenant1 ~/Downloads/theFile.json`
Im getting

```
{
            "Key": "theFile.json",
            "LastModified": "2023-12-28T22:47:14+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
            "Size": 0,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "webfile",
                "ID": "75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a"
            }
        }
```

Where the size is **0**, getting the object gives emty (zero size) file

Im I missing something? These were old bugs (all closed) in github localstack complainging the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, temporal bug of localstack/localstack:3.0.2. Latest tag resolves the problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

Was the problem resolved by using `latest` tag?
I have tried with `latest`, `3.0.2` or `3.0.1`, none of these have `expiresIn` worked.

Comment: This is not an answer, and the question you posed was answered in a previous answer.